# How to filter an object array in php by value of a parameter?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to php and I'm trying to filter an array of fields so that it only contains fields that have required property.

In javascript I would do it simply by:

```
fields.filter(field => field.required)
```

but I have no idea how to do it in php.

I'm quite new to php syntax, and have been unsuccessful with implementing array_filter. I'm trying to edit woocommerce template to only show required fields.
This is what each field has:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_email'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Email', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('EMAIL', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'clear'     => true
    );
```

My $fields array should be only objects that have required = true

```
foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {

            //billing style argument fields. start
            $key_gap_list = array('billing_last_name', 'billing_company', 'billing_country', 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state', 'billing_phone');

            if (!isset($field['placeholder']) && isset($field['label'])) {
                $field['placeholder'] = $field['label'];
            }
            if (isset($field['required']) && $field['required']) {
                $field['placeholder'] .= ' *';
            }
            if (isset($field['class'])) {
                $findClass = array_search('form-control', $field['class']);
                if ($findClass) {
                    unset($field['class'][$findClass]);
                }
            }
            $field['input_class'] = array('form-control');
            unset($field['label']);

            //billing style argument fields. end
            if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $fields[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
                $field['country'] = $checkout->get_value( $field['country_field'] );
            }

            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );

            if ($key == 'billing_last_name') {
                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Please show us an example of the Array you are filtering and the value you are searching for, and what you want the array to look like after the filtering. In short a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function would be a good start

Comment: To customize checkout fields, you should not override any template and instead use all dedicated filter hooks: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks a lot for sharing the link, I think I will be able to use the information in there to solve the problem. I will comment if I manged to fix it so you can post it as solution.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec The link provided useful info and I was able to filter the array. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by overriding the woocommerce checkout template and added custom fields and removed the ones I didn't need. The project is closed so I cannot share any code of how I did it, but I'm closing this issue.